# Ajax Script Manager blocked the jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I created a simple page just to test this out.

My page will have a textbox and a button. If you click a button the button click event on server side will write some text inside a textbox.

Then I have a jQuery function that is detecting an enter keypress of the textbox.

If it detects an enter keypress, it will click the button.

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="test" onclick="btnClick_Click" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').keypress(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            $('#<%=btnClick.ClientID%>').click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTest.Text = "btnclick click event";
}
```

It works fine for every refresh.

Then I implemented a ScriptManager.

Markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="test" onclick="btnClick_Click" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').keypress(function (e) {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                    alert('hihi');
                    $('#<%=btnClick.ClientID%>').click();
                }
            });

        </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTest.Text = "btnclick click event";
}
```

Then It only works on first enter, nut not on second enter.

Anybody ever faced this kinda issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this block of code outside scriptmanager tag and it would work fine

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').keypress(function (e) {
                    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                    if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                        alert('hihi');
                        $('#<%=btnClick.ClientID%>').click();
                    }
                });

</script>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
...
...
```

**UPDATE**

Why is your code for handling key press not inside $(document).ready ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').keypress(function (e) {
                        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                        if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                            alert('hihi');
                            $('#<%=btnClick.ClientID%>').click();
                        }
                    });
 });
```

See the following [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1661979.aspx/1?jquery%20event%20working%20in%20first%20time%20only), in which issue mentioned is similar. But the solution was instead of putting it inside document.Ready, the script to bind the click is bound every time by calling RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 0):

I would do a few things here. Firstly I would put your JS code in a separate file and delete `<script>` tag out of the UpdatePanel. (However this will also work if you put the following script directly in your `<head>` tag). This would then mean that you can't use the ClientID property - we will sort that out with a jQuery selector. Also, **you need to bind the event on document ready AND partial postback**. So in your JS...

```
//define the bind function
function bindEvents(){
    //the selector '[ID$="txtTest"]' will select any element with ID ending
    //txtTest - make sure there's only 1!!

    $('[ID$="txtTest"]').keypress(function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                alert('hihi');
                $('[ID$="txtTest"]').click();
            }
    });  
}


//bind on doc ready
$(function(){
    bindEvents();

    //and bind on partial postback too  
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindEvents()); 
});
```